# how do I depend on compiled artifacts from one project into another project in GIT CICD?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am completely new to Git and am really confused as to how to get this working. Essentially I want to have one project that uses the artifacts from multiple other projects. Is this something that can be done in Git CI ?

So for example, Project A needs the compiled artifacts from Project B and Project C to compile

I have taken a look at the documentation in GIT that shows something called **include:project** but it seems you can only reference .yml files? What if I want to use all the compiled files from a specific project?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includeproject

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't use git to get the artifacts from another project but rather some kind of package manager. E.g., when programming in node-js, you would upload the artifacts to an NPM-repo and use npm to resolve them in your other project. Can you therefore tell us more about your project? What language are you using? Are you using a tool like Gradle, Maven, NPM, Pip or similar?

Comment: If I upload my compiled artifacts to lets say Artifactory, could I download them into my Project and use them at compile time? The project consists of multiple languages such as C++ and JAVA so I want to keep the projects separated.

Comment: That is pretty much what package managers do: They upload the compiled artifacts to a repository (e.g., Artifactory) and then download it in the other project. The details depend though on what package manager you use. For Java, you might want to use Maven or Gradle. I am not so firm with C++, but in my brief experience, I used CMake there. Also, can you describe which part of the project depends on what? E.g. does the Java part depend on the C++ part?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.